# Zurb Foundation: How to make Dropdown Menus work after setting up a project via CLI

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I've made an Foundation-project by using the CLI ( foundation new myProjectName ).

The "app.scss"-file I've compiled by using CodeKit. So that a app.css file is available.

Now I want to start with Dropdown menu but I can't get the thing to work. That's what I've got so far. Based upon the index.html file which comes the installation of a foundation-project.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li><a href="#">Item No. One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item No. Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item No. Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The menu doesn't appear horizontal (as it should). Instead it stays as an unstyled unordered list vertically.

[image]

I suppose I've to include or import further files or changing something in some app.scss ...

But currently I'm really stucked because these project-directory comes with so many directories and sub-directories. A lot of the stuff seems redundant too me and confuses me.

Can someone tell me please what I've to do for getting the dropdown feature (and similar features) running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share some of my knowledge which I gained while fiddling with Foundation 5 and Foundation 6 for about 2 years.

For any Front-End Framework to be effective and make a difference, it's core functionalities should assist/implement some javascript functions (js) and styling for elements (css) that fulfill front-end design needs.

Such core scripts specific and styling specific codes are bundled and released as version for users to download and use. Zurb has also released such packages with version namely Foundation 3 to Foundation 6.

Adding to that, it's a general practice followed to provide individual files js and css files which target a specific need. This is provided in the notion of allowing the users to customize the feature according to their own needs and better understand the working of framework. The core files comprises of all such individual elements which comprises the current release of the entire framework.

## **Production Version & Development Version**

**Development Versions**

Such individual elements are the development version files of the framework. You can use them when you want to experiment with its nuances or implement your feature specific complex needs. A framework with good documentation will have the specifications which will tell about the list of interdependent files that you will require if you are including the development version files.

In the case of Foundation 6, the list of files you see inside the `foundation/dist/plugins` and `foundation/js` (both are same) are for the local development versions. You do not want to host all of these files when you deploy your site onto a hosting server.

Remember that each reference you make is a new http request and it's going to consume some good amount of valuable load time. So always try to reduce the number of references.

Foundation 6 does have a version of js file and css file to give you the complete support for everything you do using foundation 6. This is the production version.

**Minified versions are the Production versions**

The `primary reference` files which you `need` to `refer` in your front-end code are the `minified verisons` (files with a `.min` appended to the file name).

For Foundation 6, in `foundation/dist/` you can see `foundation.min.css` and `foundation.min.js` files. Those are the core ones you would need for using all the elements and features provided by Foundation 6.

You need not reference the development version files if you are referring the min versions.

**What is a minified version?**

Minified version of a file is the compressed version of file where the indentation, white-spaces and other elements which are mentioned to increase human readability are removed in the notion to reduce the file size there by improving page load time.

It's advisable to upload a minified version of you `app.css` and `app.js` or the application specific scripts and stylesheet that you create. You can use something like uglify js or other minification tools to generate your file's compressed/minified version.

### **So that's all I would ever need right?**

Well, there are some more things you need to be mindful of.

1. In general, any front end framework would use jquery. So, you will have to either give an online url reference, ex:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
   ```

   or

   download the `jquery-2.2.4.min.js` file from [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)  and refer `before` referring the `foundation.min.js` file. Not to mention, you can choose which version of jquery to use.
2. Simply quoting the references wouldn't solve the purpose. You will have to trigger a function that will watch your html scripts and render them as nice features and elements using jquery/js and css references you have mentioned.

   And all that happens, if you include this in your pages (advisably in your footer).

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).foundation();
   </script>
   ```

You are good to go if your html script resembles the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Site Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Page Content -->

  <footer>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).foundation();
    </script>  
   </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```